# Hibernate - Populate sub entity on insert

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate

Ive added 2 hibernate model objects 
First table

```
      @Entity
      @Table(name = "ACTIVITIES")
     public class ActivityMO extends ModelBase {

        @Column(name = "CA_ID", nullable = false, insertable = true,updatable = true, length = 22, precision = 0)
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "G1")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "G1", sequenceName = "CSM_ACTIVITIES_SEQ")
        private Long id;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "activityId", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
        @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
        List<ActivitiesProductsMO> relatedProducts;

    ...getters / setters
        }
```

The other table is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTIVITIES_PRODUCTS")
public class ActivitiesProductsMO {

@Column(name = "CAP_ID")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "G1")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "G1", sequenceName = "ACTIVITIES_PRODUCTS_SEQ")
private Long id;
    @Column(name = "CAP_ACTIVITY_ID")
    private Long activityId;

@Column(name = "CAP_PRODUCT_ID")
private Long productId;

...getters/setters
    }
```

**The point is to populate each db record for ActivitiesProductsMO.activityId with ActivityMO.id value**

I.e. 
If I create an activity record with id = 555
I'll get another activity_product record with activityId of 555

How can i get this to work?
Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify: If you insert a new ActivityMO, do you want to change all existing ActivitiesProductsMO to point to that ActivityMO (via its activityId mapping field) , or do you want to create a new ActivitiesProductsMO while leaving all others untouched? I guess its the second... but then my question is: Why exactly one? You defined your entity with a OneToMany, meaning that for every ActivityMO there can be multiple linked ActivityProductsMO.

Comment: Hi. Its not exactly one, it was just an example. If activityMO came with 20 activityProductMOs list then 20 new ACTIVITY_PRODUCT records need to be created and all of them need to have activityId = activityMO.id

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually trying to map the entitiy relations with long values you should use a bidirectional OneToMany relationship from ActivityMO to ActivitiesProductsMO

change ActivitiesProductsMO to:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTIVITIES_PRODUCTS")
public class ActivitiesProductsMO {

    // cut unimportant code ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAP_ACTIVITY_ID")
    private ActivityMO activityId;

    // cut unimportant code ...

}
```

If you then were to persist an ActivityMO that already has ActivitiesProductsMO entries in its relatedProducts List, the Cascade type should actually take care and create those products while filling out the CAP_ACTIVITY_ID database field with the right value.

**Another Possible Solution:**

Use a Unidirectional OneToMany:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTIVITIES")
public class ActivityMO extends ModelBase {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CAP_ACTIVITY_ID")
    List<ActivitiesProductsMO> relatedProducts;


}
```

And remove the

```
private Long activityId;
```

from your ActivitiesProductsMO class.

This should both lead to identical database structure. But in the second case you would no longer have the "backlink" inside java from *ActivitiesProductsMO* to *ActivityMO*